# Program to remove image from mp3 files

Tags: software-recommendation

Am looking for a program in Ubuntu that can remove the logo/image of an mp3 file. For example when i open Banshee (Or any other player that can show the image of a mp3 file) it shows this guy from Ecuador, Peru or some country that freaks people out. I want to remove his image from all mp3 files i have.

Just to add, this is not one of those hidden files that comes with the mp3 files folder. This is an embedded image INSIDE the mp3. Just to clarify that part and i want to strip clean the image.

Would be great a terminal command (Since for me is better) but a gui one will work as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Command line: [**Eyed3**](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/) ([Install eyed3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=eyed3))

[EyeD3](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/eyeD3.1.html) is a Python program and module that provides the ability 
to read and write ID3 tags (v1.x and v2.3/v2.4). It also decodes MP3 
headers (bit rate, sample frequency, play time, etc.).

It has a command line option `--remove-images` or you can use `--add image=""`.

And it is inside USC.

If you want a GUI option: [**Easytag**](http://easytag.sourceforge.net/) ([Install easytagaac](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/easytagaac))

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ffmpeg` command line tool for this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i audio_file_with_artwork.mp3 -vn -c copy audio_without_artwork.mp3
```

Explanation of options:

```
-y        Overwrite output files without asking
-i        [input] Defines input file
-vn       Blocks all video streams (also embedded images) from being selected
-c copy   Do not re-encode the stream
```

You can learn more about the tool and options using `man ffmpeg`.

Comment: Doesn't produce any errors, but also doesn't remove the image for me.  ffmpeg v.4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1+esm3

Answer (score 0):

I have opened the file with audacity and exported it. It worked.
But to keep the audio quality you show save it in raw format. To do that click on Export->Export as Audio. Then the quality of the output file won't change, but it will increase the file a lot.

An other solution, which is not increasing the file, but keeps the quality is from the most voted answer here. My answer just adds the commands which are missing in the other answer. Also my answer improves the other answer because the command is with remove-all-images in newer versions of the eyed3 program. First go inside the folder where your mp3 files are and run:

```
sudo apt-get install -y eyed3
eyeD3 --remove-all-images ./*.mp3
```

This will remove the images from the .mp3 and won't change the quality.
It can work for many files with one line, without adding more lines to the command above or writing scripts about it.

Comment: If you save it in in an other format it does not harm the audio quality